# Flutter Firebase Storage 'No App Check Token Request'

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, firebase-storage

```
When uploading files to **firebase storage**, i get
```

> "No App Check Token For Request"

```
but i didn't enable App Check in my firebase, uploading to cloud firestore works fine 
and my internet connection is also stable.
```

[image]

```
Here is my upload to storage function
```

[image]

Comment: Check your firebase storage rules.

Comment: thanks i changed the firebase storage rules to allow reads and write without any specifications and that fixed my problem

Comment: Updating the rules and allowing anyone to write in you data doesn't seem to be the best option, you gotta figure it out why are you receiving this message since you didn't activated the App Check